# Getting the Text Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my current process, In the view, when the user clicks on the checkbox, it took the @Item.Extra_Item_Price and Add to the Total Price.

```
<div class="product__price m-t-5">
  <input class="product__price product__price--large" name="TotalPrice" value="" id="TotalPriceS" type="hidden" />
  <span class="product__price product__price--large" data-original='@Model.ProductPrice'>Rs.@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductPrice)</span>
</div>
<div class="product-var p-tb-30">
  <div class="product-quantity product-var__item d-flex align-items-center">
    <span class="product-var__text">Quantity: </span>
    <form class="quantity-scale m-l-20">
      <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()">-</div>
      <input type="number" id="number" name="number" value="1" />
      <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="thisChecked(this)">+</div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4 class="font--regular m-b-20">Add Some Extra</h4> 
    @if (Model.CustomizableFoods.Count != 0)
    { 
    foreach (var item in Model.CustomizableFoods)
    { 
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="thisChecked(this)" value="@item.Extra_Item_Price"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; @item.ExtraItem - @item.Extra_Item_Price </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
       }   
      }
  </div>
```

When the User again unchecks the checkbox it subtracts the amount added.

Here I want to do on submit, want to take the @Item.ExtraItem values that are checked in the view and assign to the **Input field** to sent to the controller.

Any way of doing this?

This is the Amount updating the current javascript

```
<script>
        function thisChecked(el) {
            var closest_price_element = $(el).closest('.product-details-box').find('span.product__price');
            var amount = parseFloat(closest_price_element.data('original')) ?? 0; //getting attr value ..

            $('.product-var input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                amount += parseFloat($(this).val()); //loop and addiing items amt
            });
            
            closest_price_element.text('Rs.' + amount); //change value of price
            document.getElementById("TotalPriceS").value = amount;
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, you need addition of all checked items and total you need to put in hidden input ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired functionality of taking the checked @Item.ExtraItem values in the view and assigning them to an input field to send to the controller on submit, you can modify your JavaScript code.
Here's an example of how you can accomplish this:

```
<script>
    function thisChecked(el) {
        var closest_price_element = $(el).closest('.product-details-box').find('span.product__price');
        var amount = parseFloat(closest_price_element.data('original')) ?? 0; //getting attr value ..
        
        var selectedItems = [];
        
        $('.product-var input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            amount += parseFloat($(this).val()); //loop and adding items amt
            selectedItems.push($(this).val());
        });
        
        closest_price_element.text('Rs.' + amount); //change value of price
        document.getElementById("TotalPriceS").value = amount;
        
        // Assign selected items to a hidden input field
        var selectedItemsInput = document.getElementById("SelectedItems");
        selectedItemsInput.value = selectedItems.join(",");
    }
</script>
```

In the above code, I added a new hidden input field with the id "SelectedItems" to store the selected @Item.ExtraItem values. The selected values are stored in the selectedItems array, and then they are joined with commas and assigned to the hidden input field's value.

Make sure to add the hidden input field to your HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SelectedItems" id="SelectedItems" value="" />
```

By doing this, when the form is submitted, the selected @Item.ExtraItem values will be available in the controller through the "SelectedItems" parameter.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.